# Pandas put trash digits after real data while reading a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using read_csv to read a file but when I look at what I've put into a dataframe it shows many more digits that are in the original file.

Code:

```
   df = pd.read_csv(f'{name}.csv', sep=',', decimal='.', dtype={'col1': str, 'column_with_trash': float})

   df[df['col1'] == '0001'].to_excel('1.xlsx')
   df['column_with_trash'] = df['column_with_trash'] - 1524684.3740493
   df[df['col1'] == '0001'].to_excel('2.xlsx')
```

Csv file looks like this:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,column_with_trash
0001,TP,2021-12-31,T,N,2130875.40078,1524684.374049378
```

I don't even do operations and I still get different output than input I've put in.
When I open 1.xlsx file I can subtract 1524684.3740493 from the output (which seems to end just like the input - pic) and I'll get 0,00000007799826562404630000 as there are digits there that there were not in the beginning.
In the 2.xlsx file I get the same result.

How can this be? I've tried float_precision="high", "round_trip" and None, nothing changed. The difference is at 9th decimal place and it messes up my calculations. `df['column_with_trash'] = df['column_with_trash'].round(9)`, which should work, does not change a thing within these outputs.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGPC1.png)

Comment: Excel doesn't work with infinite precision, but also saving data lose some precision. Check your differences: 16 digits are correct. You cannot pretend much more. -- I think double-precision floats have 17 or 18 digit precision.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi that's kind of my point - I want only the data I'm putting in but just reading it and saving adds digits that I do not want at the end. Numbers' length isn't even so I can't just cut the end. Just reading "1524684.374049378" from a file gives me "1524684.37404937879982656240463" or something like that. I want only the orginal number.

Comment: AFAIK excel to excel may not preserve the numbers. I had many cases of that in past. But it is Microsoft: keep backward compatibility also in case of small "bugs"/imprecision. I think Python changed the way to go from float to string and back in a better way (and I think round trip compatible). I think 10 years ago and there should be a PIP which describe the methods and rink to scientific paper. (or just use a binary format) Because "Excel", I'm not sure you can implement you own string that will force Excel to give you the expected number. Maybe Googling or in SuperUser. Very niche precision

Comment: Note: AFAIK Python changed the methods to deliver the shortest string which give the same number. But with if you round (as you did), both numbers must be equal. Note: the 9 decimal is really the 15 decimal in a normalized form (like it is in floats). So just round less. or just forget. It is possible they are exactly the same number (internally), but just a different representation (one of the many possible). (but again, in my experience Excel may change numbers a little bit).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks, yes it's the Excel's fault, it even changes the data after simply loading it from a csv file 

Answer (score 1):

It's MS Excel who puts these trash characters there, not pandas. After reading from csv file, as well as when opening pandas' xlsx file it creates imaginated numbers at the end and distorts my results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).